# Difference between Protoporphyrin and Porphyrin?

Tags: biochemistry, chemical-biology, structural-biology

I understand that Porphyrin is defined as 4 pyrole rings linked by methenyl bridges. When this porphyrin ring is associated with a Ferrous ion (Fe 2+) we get the Heme molecule. However my book mentions that Heme is a complex of Protoporhyrin IX and Ferrous ion. So what is the difference between a Porphyrin ring and a Protoporphyrin ring?

Comment: There's no difference, protoporphyrin IX is one of a large number of porphyrins. What you think of as porphyrin is actually [porphine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porphine), a parent compound of the group, a "core" of protoporphyrin IX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](https://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-porphyrin-and-protoporphyrin/):

> Protoporphyrin is a derivative of porphyrin. The key difference between porphyrin and protoporphyrin is that porphyrin is a group of aromatic chemicals which has four modified pyrrole subunits interconnected to each other, whereas protoporphyrin is a derivative of porphyrin which has propionic acid groups.

Protoporphyrine contains [porphine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porphine) as core which is the simplest of the porphyrin chain. Picture from Wikipedia:

[image]